# Magento 1.7.0.2 Checkout shipping

Tags: magento

I have a small problem with jquery that I want to use in my magento one page checkout.
I currently use flat rate for international delivery that is set to 0 because I have a variable costs of shipping.

For this reason I have a jquery email enquiry that sends all contents of the shopping cart in e-mail.

Now what I want to do is: when the customer arrives and selects flat rate delivery option I want to disable the Continue button and enable Email Enquiry button, but that does not work in my checkout. It does in jsfiddle. I think this is due to the fact that shipping methods are in available.phtml and buttons are in different file - shipping_methods.phtml. Any help will be appreciated

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var shippingMethod = new ShippingMethod('co-shipping-method-form', "<?php echo $this-    >getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod') ?>");
//]]>
</script>
<div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional') ?>
</div>
<div class="buttons-set" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
    <p class="back-link"><a href="#" onclick="checkout.back(); return false;"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
    <button id="the_other_button" type="button" title="Email Enquiry" class="button" onclick="javascript:readEmailInfo();"><span><span style="padding: 0 13px;">Email Enquiry</span></span></button>
    <button id="the_button" type="button" class="button" onclick="shippingMethod.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>

    <span id="shipping-method-please-wait" class="please-wait" style="display:none;">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo 
$this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" 
class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
    </span>
</div>
</form>
<script>
    if ($("#s_method_flatrate_flatrate:checked")){
        $('#the_button').hide();
        $('#the_other_button').show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, this is doing something that is close. I've added else clause to display continue button if other option is selected. However it seems that my condition is not working... should the id be first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    if (jQuery("#s_method_flatrate_flatrate").is(":checked")){
        jQuery('#the_button').hide();
        jQuery('#the_other_button').show();
    }
</script>
```

`$` is also used by Magento's default `prototype.js`, which will conflict with jQuery's `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by this:

`<script>
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    if ($j("#s_method_flatrate_flatrate").is(":checked"))
    {
        $j('#the_button').hide();
        $j('#the_other_button').show();
    }
</script>`

By using this you can resolve jQuery Conflict.